# Why does Marshmallow return empty for multiple items but returns a single item when I use first()

Tags: python, flask-restful, marshmallow

Im trying to get data from two tables in one query through flask-mysqlAlchemy, and I get all the data. But when I try to dump it through flask-marshmallow, it shows an array with a lot of empty objects. But if I put .first() on the query it shows the first results from both tables.

I created a class that contains every field from both tables and it works like a model entity, Im not sure if its needed but here is it:

```
class HotelInfoReview(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'hotel_info_review'
    country_area = db.Column(db.String(45), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    hotel_id = db.Column(db.String(32), unique=True, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    hotel_name = db.Column(db.Text)
    hotel_url = db.Column(db.Text)
    hotel_address = db.Column(db.Text)
    review_score = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    review_qty = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    clean = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    comf = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    loct = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    fclt = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    staff = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    vfm = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    wifi = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    uuid = (db.Column(db.String, nullable=True, primary_key=True))
    review_title = db.Column(db.Text)
    review_url = db.Column(db.Text)
    review_score = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=True)
    review_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    reviewer_name = db.Column(db.Text)
    hash_reviewer_name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    reviewer_location = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    posting_conts = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    positive_content = db.Column(db.Text)
    negative_content = db.Column(db.Text)
    tag_n1 = db.Column(db.Text)
    tag_n2 = db.Column(db.Text)
    tag_n3 = db.Column(db.Text)
    tag_n4 = db.Column(db.Text)
    tag_n5 = db.Column(db.Text)
    staydate = db.Column(db.Text)
```

Then I defined the output method like docs says:

```
class HotelInfoReviewSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('country_area', 'hotel_id', 'hotel_name', 'hotel_url', 'hotel_address', 'review_score', 'review_qty',
                  'clean', 'comf', 'loct', 'fclt', 'staff', 'vfm', 'wifi', 'uuid', 'review_title', 'review_url',
                  'review_date', 'reviewer_name', 'hash_reviewer_name', 'reviewer_location', 'posting_conts',
                  'positive_content', 'negative_content', 'tag_n1', 'tag_n2', 'tag_n3', 'tag_n4', 'tag_n5')


hotel_info_review_schema = HotelInfoReviewSchema()
hotels_info_review_schema = HotelInfoReviewSchema(many=True)
```

Finally I created a route for dump results:

```
@app.route('/HotelsAndReviews')
def get_reviews():
    data = db.session.query(HotelInfo, HotelReview)
    .join(HotelReview, HotelReview.hotel_id == HotelInfo.hotel_id)
    .filter((HotelReview.review_date.between('2018-01-01', '2019-12-12')))

    result = hotels_info_review_schema.dump(data)
    return jsonify(result)
```

What am I missing? I know that question has been ansawered but the ansawer dont works for me, since I am already applying that answer in my code.
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Try using .all() after query, this retrieves all the data, if still doesnt work import ModelSchema from marshmallow_sqlalchemy and use the ModelSchema class instead in ma.schema. so shall look like this "class HotelInfoReviewSchema(ModelSchema):"